# generate URL for mpd videos

Tags: url, mpeg-dash, dash.js

I hope that I am posting using the right tags.

I added the `dash.js` player to a page in my website

I did create some `mpd` files from `mp4` ones.

I wanted to know how can I generate `URL` for these files so that my app can access them.

In case it will help I am using Apache2 to serve my application.

Answer (score 1):

The mpd file provides an index with pointers to the individual steams for your video - e.g. the different bitrate video files, the Audi stream, and subtitles etc.

The pointers in the mpd file are relative or absolute URL's which the client, e.g. the browser can access.

To allow the browser access the mpd itself you just have to put it someplace in your server file structure that clients can access, or that the server will redirect client requests for video to.

The online apache documentation provides an overview of how you can match URL requests to file locations:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/urlmapping.html